# Windows Media Center: cannot change the volume

Tags: windows-7, audio, windows-media-center

I have a home theater set up using Windows Media Center. The computer running it isn't exactly the greatest computer out there but it does the job well. I have recently installed an nvida gforce 210 into it to make the system run better, before hand i was just using the onboard VGA and audio connectors.

This new video card has an HDMI port, what im using now, the audio does work from it. No, the problem lies only with TV, I have an HDHomeRun Prime streaming video to it, I cannot change the volume of the audio from this stream. The same goes for recorded TV, I can mute it, just not change the volume.

I have installed the latest drivers from the nvida web site, in fact that is waht gave me the ability to mute, before hand I couldn't even do that. It seems set up correctly, again I the problem only lies there, I can control the volume in netflix, music, movies, dvds, what have you.

Please help, thanks.